# Hypothesis Testing terminology

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

I am studying now Hypothesis Testing. I use for it book `High-Yield Biostatistics, Epidemiology, and Public Health` and videos of Brandon Foltz (recommending these videos for everyone, they are great!) from here https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFrjdcImgcQVyFbK04MBEhA .

In `High-Yield Biostatistics, Epidemiology, and Public Health` author uses terms like `Accept` or `Reject` hypothesis. But Brandon Foltz in his video here  says:

`As researchers we either reject the null hypothesis or fail to reject the null hypothesis; we do not accept the null.`

So, which terminology is more right way to talk about hypothesis: `Accept` and `Reject` or `Reject` and `Fail to reject` ?

Comment: Yes it is duplicate. I did not found these question before asking. Sorry for that. But I also want to point, that the link provided in the answer of this question by **Pio** gives better explanation of the topic then answers in other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reject` and `Fail to reject` since when you're testing your hypothesis you basically challenge it based on some data. It might happen, that your data is just not the right kind/proper sample that could `Reject` the null hypothesis. This does not mean that the null hypothesis is true, it just means that the null hypothesis describes better your data, than your alternative hypothesis.

In case you `Reject` the null hypothesis you are `Accept`-ing the alternative hypothesis. Here is a [short article](http://statistics.about.com/od/Inferential-Statistics/a/Why-Say-Fail-To-Reject.htm) about this topic.

Comment: So we can say `we accept alternative hypothesis` but we cant say `we accept null hypothesis`. Instead of `we accept null hypothesis` we have to say `we reject null hypothesis`. Am I right?

Comment: I think you wanted to say `we fail to reject the null hypothesis`. Just think about the the actual meaning of the words accept and fail to reject and how are they different.

Comment: My mistake. I wanted to say: So we can say `we accept alternative hypothesis` but we cant say `we accept null hypothesis`. Instead of `we accept null hypothesis` we have to say `we failed to reject null hypothesis`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.